# How to save string in variable partially in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Is there a way to store strings in a variable (javascript), like in php?

```
<code>
$string = "Counting: ";

for($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++){
   $string .= $x;
}

$string .= ":Counting END";

echo $string;

</code>
```

I want to loop some JS object array between the string as I did above in php.

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate string in js by using `+`

```js
var string = "Counting: ";

for (var $x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {

  string += $x;
  
}

string += ":Counting END";

console.log(string);
```

Comment: *Note*: You have to make sure, that `string` is a string before adding numbers otherwise it will be treatened as integers and sum up.

Comment: You’re missing `var $x` somewhere. Otherwise `$x` will end up being a global variable.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert Good catch! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript

```
var string = "Counting: ";
var x;

for(x = 1; x <= 10; x++){

   string += x;
}

string += ":Counting END";

document.write(string);
```

Comment: What’s with `var i`? I think you meant `var x`…

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question posed by the OP, yes, one may store strings in a JavaScript variable as one would in PHP. Translating such code from PHP to JavaScript  usually requires little more than removing the "$" from a PHP variable and using the keyword `var` or possibly `let` to declare a JavaScript variable. However, one should note that JavaScript overloads the "+" operator, permitting its use for addition as well as concatenation depending on the context.  PHP, in contrast, has a distinct operator for concatenation, namely the dot and for addition it reserves the plus sign.  So, the PHP concatenation-assignment operator allows for code like the following:

```
<?php

$res = 1;
var_dump($res);

$res .= 2;

var_dump($res);
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/urh18#output)

The concatenation-assignment operator creates a string context which allows for the variable's integer value to be coerced into the string "1".  The operator appends the string "2", and assigns the final result to the variable which now contains a string value of "12".

If you were to literally translate this code into JavaScript, you will get very different results, as follows:

```js
var res = 1;
console.log(res);

res += 2;

console.log(res);
```

In JavaScript, the "+=" always performs an addition-assignment when numbers are involved.  To get the same results in JavaScript as in this PHP example, one may code as follows:

```js
var res = 1;
var str = res.toString();
str += "2";
console.log(str);
```